# Apache does not work

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, ipv6

i rebooted server and apache stops responding but is running.

Why is this happening, can blame ipv6?

Error log:

```
[Sun Jan 23 08:25:17 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jan 23 08:44:31 2011] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun Jan 23 08:44:31 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Jan 23 08:44:31 2011] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Jan 23 08:44:32 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jan 23 09:09:50 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Jan 23 09:09:51 2011] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun Jan 23 09:09:51 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Jan 23 09:09:51 2011] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Jan 23 09:09:51 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
```

lsof -i | grep LIST

```
portmap   2404     rpc    4u  IPv4   4801       TCP *:sunrpc (LISTEN)
rpc.statd 2439 rpcuser    7u  IPv4   4949       TCP *:925 (LISTEN)
sshd      2605    root    3u  IPv6   5371       TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sendmail  2644    root    4u  IPv4   5538       TCP localhost.localdomain:smtp                                                                                                                                                        (LISTEN)
httpd     3873    root    3u  IPv6  14406       TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     3874  apache    3u  IPv6  14406       TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     3875  apache    3u  IPv6  14406       TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     3876  apache    3u  IPv6  14406       TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     3877  apache    3u  IPv6  14406       TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     3878  apache    3u  IPv6  14406       TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     3879  apache    3u  IPv6  14406       TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     3880  apache    3u  IPv6  14406       TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     3881  apache    3u  IPv6  14406       TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Iptables:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             my-ip-adress-xx.local tcp dpt:http

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp any
ACCEPT     esp  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     ah   --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251         udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:ipp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ipp
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Comment: do not just show errorlog... show the other log entry near the time as well.

Answer (score 2):

The default firewall rules are blocking you. The RH-Firewall-1-INPUT rule loads first, and finds the deny rule, before it gets to your allow later in the INPUT rules. Try looking at /etc/sysconfig/iptables, and modifying the RH-Firewall-1-INPUT rule to allow you to access via tcp port 80.

```
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```